# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.GetEnumerator() Method Not Found

Tags: json, linq, azure

I am trying to Publish my Web Application  on Azure, using Visual Studio 2013. When I login to my azure account I get this error. 
I then re-install the Json.Net package but had the same error. I was searching for the solution but not found any. Please help!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3kfs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this? http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/11/29/fixing-jarray-getenumerator-method-not-found-bug

> The Cause

In Json.NET 5.0.5 I changed JArray.GetEnumerator’s visibility from interface explicit to public. The side effect of GetEnumerator being public is the C# compiler will no longer add a IEnumerable cast to foreach loops. The cast is required when GetEnumerator is interface explicit and is only accessible when the object is cast to IEnumerable.

The error then occurs when an application or package that has a foreach loop over a JArray and is compiled with a public GetEnumerator is run using an older version of Json.NET, possible out of the GAC, where GetEnumerator is not public. Because there is no cast to IEnumerable then .NET can’t find the GetEnumerator method and an exception is thrown.

> tl;dr; just tell me how to fix it

If you’re an end user and you get this error then make sure the version of Json.NET your application is loading is 5.0.8. If you have 5.0.8 in your \bin directory and you still get this error then check the GAC as well and update it if necessary.

If you’re a package author and a user reports getting this error from your code then downgrade the version of Json.NET your package is using to 5.0.4, recompile and release a new version of your package. If you can’t downgrade then another option is to add an IEnumerable cast to the erroring foreach loop.